# wmic diskdrive get status C: drive

Tags: batch-file, cmd, server, wmic

I need to get the *status* of a specific drive so I can log that data, along with available space etc.

If you enter at command prompt:

```
   wmic diskdrive get status
```

You get a response from all drives -- how do I narrow down the scope to just `C:` or `D:`? The disks are single volume, no raid array etc..

Comment: I don't know if this script can help you or not ? [Check Disk drives for errors and fix them](http://pastebin.com/tVdZTkP4)

Comment: Not sure if that's quite it... : ) 
I was hoping there was simply an extension of the status switch - I've tried a gazillion permutations but no joy - and can't find anything on't'interweb!

Comment: You have a fallacy in your question. WMIC DISKDRIVE reports on physical drives, but C: and D: are volumes - not the same thing. A single drive may have multiple partitions, for example one for C: and one for D:. Or a single volume may be striped across multiple physical drives.

Comment: If you wish to update your question by providing all of the information you are trying to get about each of your drives, then we may be able to help guide you appropriately.

Comment: [The Windows command prompt is *NOT* a DOS prompt!](https://scalibq.wordpress.com/2012/05/23/the-windows-command-prompt-is-not-a-dos-prompt/)

Comment: `wmic LogicalDisk WHERE DriveType=3 GET DeviceID,FreeSpace,Size` (`DriveType=3` filters for local drives)...

Comment: @aschipfl - The OP wants the status, not the freespace or size. One would think LogicalDisk would provide the info, but the Status value is always blank, so it appears to be useless for this case.

Comment: @dbenham, it was just an example to show that there is an `LogicalDisk` verb also; I did not test it though; I agree the return value of `Status` is strange, particularly because the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394173(v=vs.85).aspx) says something different; anyway, I do not know if `Status` is *always* empty, or if it is empty only in case of no problems, but I cannot test it, since my disks work (un)fortunately...

Comment: @aschipfl - The LogicalDisk status seems to be non-functional. The status for the DiskDrive class gives me "OK".

Comment: If there is another way to get a disk status...? 

I need to be able to align the 'OK' to a drive so it can be logged. 

I suppose if you can marry up the results of 'WMIC DISKDRIVE GET Availability,Index,Caption' results to the 'OK's, then that's something, but not great?

> WMIC DISKDRIVE GET Availability,Index,Caption,Status

Comment: I'll go back to me last comment "update your question by providing all of the information you are trying to get about each of your drives".